# Arc jumping from high resistance to low resistance path

Tags: high-voltage, arc, transient-suppression

Trying to make sense of how to cut current on a high-voltage system without turning everything into plasma.

Specifically, I'm wondering whether you could reduce the current by going gradually (but very quickly) through higher and higher resistor to the point where you only cut a very low current.

But at the same time, would an arc form at the "transition" between a very low resistance path (nominal operation) and a much higher resistance path.

Ex :

1. Nominal operation / low resistance path
2. a high resistor is put in // with the low resistance path
3. the low resistance path is opened and only leaves the high resistance path
4. the high resistance path / low current is opened

Would the transition between 2 and 3 cause an arc?

Comment: If you're sweeping through the resistances as quickly as the interruption with no resistors, not that much changes. This sounds like flyback. Would a snubber not be easier?

Comment: First define your system. What is the "high voltage system"? Is this a power source with some known voltage, current [capacity], frequency, impedance, etc.? What is "current" -- load current? Fault (short circuit) current? Arc flash? Who's responsible for extinguishing the arc, is this a fusing application? (Or, perhaps, a potential alternative to fuses.) And, any extenuating considerations, like size, cost, power dissipation, etc.?

Comment: What does "going gradually (but very quickly)" actually mean?